# Clojure: apply a function to leaf nodes of a map

Tags: clojure

How can you apply a function to leaf nodes of a (nested) map? For example, let's have this map:

```
{:a 0
 :b {:c 1}
 :d [{:e 2} {:f 3}]}
```

Let's say we want to increment all leaf nodes in this map and produce the following result:

```
{:a 1
 :b {:c 2}
 :d [{:e 3} {:f 4}]}
```

Currently, I'm thinking of using the map-zipper from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15020649/385505) and editing the map via the `clojure.zip` functions. However, I'm not sure how to iterate through the zipper and how to identify leaf nodes. What functions should I look at? Is there a simpler solution without zippers?

Could something like the following work (provided there is a `leaf-node?` predicate testing if a location in zipper is a leaf node)?

```
(require '[clojure.zip :as zip])

(defn inc-leaf-nodes
  [loc]
  (if (zip/end? loc)
    (zip/node loc)
    (recur (zip/next (if (leaf-node? loc)
                       (zip/edit loc inc)
                       loc)))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `leaf-node?` function could be implemented given an appropriate definition of a leaf, but there are at least two issues with the proposed `inc-leaf-nodes`:

- the zipper implementation you linked to uses map entries as nodes, so you cannot simply pass `inc` to `zip/edit` – you would have to wrap it in a helper function that would apply it in the value position;
- that zipper also doesn't treat non-map values as branches, so it would not descend into the vector `[{:e 3} {:f 4}]` – you would need a different zipper to overcome this problem.

Assuming that a leaf is something that is not a map, set or a sequential collection and the mapping function is to be applied only in the value position in maps, you could define a `map-leaves` function like so:

```
(defn map-leaves [f x]
  (cond
    (map? x) (persistent!
               (reduce-kv (fn [out k v]
                            (assoc! out k (map-leaves f v)))
                 (transient {})
                 x))
    (set? x) (into #{} (map #(map-leaves f %)) x)
    (sequential? x) (into [] (map #(map-leaves f %)) x)
    :else (f x)))
```

At the REPL:

```
(map-leaves inc {:a 0 :b {:c 1 :d [{:e 2} {:f 3}]}})
;= {:a 1, :b {:c 2, :d [{:e 3} {:f 4}]}}

(map-leaves inc {:a 0 :b {:c 1 :d [{:e 2} {:f 3} {:g #{1 2 3}}]}})
;= {:a 1, :b {:c 2, :d [{:e 3} {:f 4} {:g #{4 3 2}}]}}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you think using `clojure.zip` is an overkill for this task or simply not an appropriate solution?

Comment: @jindrichm No worries. Just edited the answer to explain why the zipper you linked to wouldn't work. You could look into implementing a different zipper if you wanted to use it in other transformations later, but if you're only interested in `map-leaves`, the above may be the simpler approach. (Incidentally, `clojure.walk` is the simplest solution to the variant of this problem where the function is to be applied in the key position as well.)